# Get Client IP in AWS ELB with Passthrough TCP SSL - Apache

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, nginx, networking, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have an ELB setup with Apache Web server on the EC2 instance. For compliance reasons, we had to configure TCP Passthrough SSL (HTTPS terminates at the Instance and not on the ELB). We are using the Classic Load Balancer.

We need the client's IP address, the issue however is that we are getting the IP of the ELB. We tried the logging solution suggested on the AWS website, its not working.

Given that it's an encrypted connection to the instance, whether the ELB proxy can modify the request to add X-Forwarded-For header is questionable.

Have you solved this issue before? Please help.

Documentation we looked at:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-proxy-protocol.html
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/

Our Configuration:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-tcp-passthrough.html

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is your setup? It should all be TCP, not SSL.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-capture-client-ip-addresses/ and go to: Classic Load Balancers with TCP/SSL Listeners (Apache)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your usecase is described here:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-capture-client-ip-addresses/

go to: Classic Load Balancers with TCP/SSL Listeners (Apache)